# Can we use two Laravel project one for web services & another for Backend admin panel with single database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a doubt that can i use two Laravel project that is one for web services and another one for backend admin panel separately with single database.How much it will fast if i use separately.

and If i use both in single Laravel project will any problem in term of speed and data loading.

Please anyone elaborate this.

Comment: I don't see why not or why it'd have an effect on loading speeds.  I think you'd be creating a lot of redundancy having two projects using the same database.

Comment: Remember to cache config, besides that this question is so broad... and someone even bothered to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could setup multiple Laravel / PHP applications to share the same database. However, that's probably not what you want to do.

Looks like you are concerned about having the same database being used for your private and public interfaces. As long you setup your authentication properly, there is no problem in doing that.

In your routes files, for ex. `web.php`, make sure to protect any routes that access private data with the `auth` middleware.

For ex.:

```
// Public Routes
...

// Ex. Home...
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});


// Private Routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'app', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // My private routes here...
});
```

I also recommend having separate controllers for public and private routes. This way, when you are creating a new "public" route, it will point to a method in a "public" controller. And when creating a new "private" route, it will point to a method in a "private" controller. This is not necessary, but it helps separating your private and public logic / data.

When it comes to performance, it won't be an issue as long you index your tables properly.

Comment: Thanks, But my mobile application will be heavy traffic. I know it will be ok for normal traffic, but in case of heavy traffic may be some problem in term of speed if  we use both in single project.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even think its an issue. Just updated my answer to reflect that. I wouldn't add unnecessary complexity to a new app. Good luck.